# Python group consecutive elements of a list into two's without repetition

Tags: python, list

I got the the list below

```py
[[0,1],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3]]
```

Using Python, how can I iterate through the list to get

```py
[[0,1],[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[0,1],[2,3]]
```

?

Comment: what if a sublist has an odd number of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we do is we first flatten the list and then we index the flattened list to the 2d list

```py
l1 = [[0,1],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3]]
def fix(l1):
    l1 = [item for sublist in l1 for item in sublist]
    l1 = [l1[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l1), 2)]
    return l1
l1 = fix(l1)
print(l1)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip(item[::2], item[1::2])` to grab pairs of elements, turn these tuples into lists using `map()` and `list()`, and then generate the final result using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` and `list()`:

```py
from itertools import chain

list(map(list, chain.from_iterable(zip(item[::2], item[1::2]) for item in data)))
```

This outputs:

```py
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to one solution for this is taking advantage of the standard library itertools chain function, specifically, `chain.from_iterable`  It flattens out the elements in an iterable of iterables allowing you to reconstitute them into pairs, for example.

```
from itertools import chain

twos_list = []
pair_list = []
for x in chain.from_iterable([[0,1],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,1,2,3]]):
    pair_list.append(x)
    if len(pair_list) == 2:
        twos_list.append(pair_list)
        pair_list = []
        
print(twos_list)
```

```
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [0, 1], [2, 3]]
```